# Does Outlook appointment add-in support for iphone outlook app

Tags: outlook, office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins, office365-apps

if i develop a outlook add-in for appointments, does it  visible on iPhone's outlook .i tested `<MobilSettings>` as below  but didn't work?

```
 <FormSettings>
    <Form xsi:type="ItemRead">
      <DesktopSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://sampleaddin.com/index.html"/>
        <RequestedHeight>250</RequestedHeight>
      </DesktopSettings>
    </Form>
  </FormSettings>
```

Answer (score 1):

Only mail read is supported on Outlook Mobile at this time.

That means MobileMessageReadCommandSurface is the only ExtensionPoint you should declare in the [mobile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/add-mobile-support#code-considerations) section of your manifest.

For more information please see [Add-ins for Outlook mobile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/outlook-mobile-addins)

Answer (score 0):

You can support mobile if you target read emails only.  Then you can declare the PhoneSettings node:

```
<FormSettings>
<Form xsi:type="ItemRead">
  <DesktopSettings>
    <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://myaddin/index.html"/>
    <RequestedHeight>250</RequestedHeight>
  </DesktopSettings>
  <TabletSettings>
    <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://myaddin/index.html" />
    <RequestedHeight>250</RequestedHeight>
  </TabletSettings>
  <PhoneSettings>
    <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://myaddin/index.html" />
  </PhoneSettings>
</Form>
</FormSettings>
```